# What is the most efficient way to return multiple values from a class method in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have multiple classes with methods like the one below:

```
@property
def max_ill(self):
    maxval = max(self.illarr)
    maxpts = [idx for idx,val in enumerate(self.illarr) if val==maxval]
    maxpts = [ self.roomgrid.ptsdict[pt].ptid for pt in maxpts ]
    return {'data':maxval,"points":maxpts}
```

What I'd like to do is to split this property into two such that I can access the `max_ill['data']` and `max_ill['points']` as individual properties like `.max_ill_data` and `.max_ill_points`. This will aid in auto-code-compeletion and also free me from having to remember what each property returns. However, as you can see above, calling each property individually will result in some of the calculations being repeated.

So, is there an elegant (non-hacky) way that I can run the calculation just once and assign both values? I know that I could call a function within the `def __init__` constructor function and set these values. But I don't foresee myself needing these values everytime I instantiate a class (hence the use of `@property`).

Is this a place where setter might be useful ?

Comment: You don't need methods or the constructor to define class variables

Comment: Agree. But I don't have a straight-forward class variable. If you see the the third line, the property is being calculated by performing some operations on a variable called self.illarr which was set at instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is something known as lazy-property but that also has it's drawbacks in case your `self.illarr` could change over time. In short it would be something like this:

```
def max_ill(self):
    # Helper function to create the needed values. Not to be used directly
    maxval = max(self.illarr)
    maxpts = [idx for idx,val in enumerate(self.illarr) if val==maxval]
    maxpts = [ self.roomgrid.ptsdict[pt].ptid for pt in maxpts ]
    # Save the calculated values as attributes
    self._max_ill_data = maxval
    self._max_ill_points = maxpts

@property
def max_ill_data(self):
    try:
        # Get the saved value (raises an AttributeError when not existing)
        return self._max_ill_data
    except AttributeError:
        # We found None, so call the method that creates these and return it afterwards
        self.max_ill()
        return self._max_ill_data

@property
def max_ill_points(self):
    try:
        return self._max_ill_points
    except AttributeError:
        self.max_ill()
        return self._max_ill_points
```

So the `max_ill` is responsible for calculating the values and the properties only return the saved value or if there is no such attribute call the function that creates these.

There are also some libraries that implement `lazyproperties` even with tied parameters so this is just to illustrate how they (could) simplified work or if you don't want to add dependencies.

Comment: That was quick! I don't foresee self.illarr getting changed in my case but thank you for pointing out that potential drawback.

Comment: In the general case, I'd suggest using `try: return self._max_ill_date`, `except AttributeError:`, `self.max_ill()`, `return self._max_ill_date`; using the EAFP pattern means you don't have to worry about the possibility that `None` may be a legitimate value for the attribute. Alternatively, you make a private class variable `__sentinel = object()` and use that as the `getattr` default and test `ret is self.__sentinel`, so you have a unique "not found" value that isn't a legitimate real value.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I always forget [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) ... I'll edit the answer. Thank you for pointing this out.